# via $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER blocking

Tags: php

My PHP engine keep website searched keywords and system ignores some useless keywords via:

```
if (strpos($system_search, 'useless keyword') === FALSE AND 
strpos($system_search, 'waste time') === FALSE AND 
strpos($system_search, 'viagra') === FALSE AND 
net_match_ban($bad_ip, $remote_ip))
{
```

also system ignore some user agents via:

```
if (!stripos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], 'Baiduspider') &&
!stripos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], 'Sogou') &&)
{
$db->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO sphinx (`keyword`, `ip_adress`, `time`) VALUES  ('$tmp_sphinx', '$remote_ip', '$time')");
}
```

I want block some referrers using  $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER

How can i ignore referrers?

Comment: pointless as REFERER is browser set, so easily altered.

Comment: Not *pointless* altogether as most UAs will set the header appropriately, but certainly of little integrity. Nice to try but not sufficiently certain to work. What's the exact question though, how to `exit` the script if you get a match?

Comment: $db->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO sphinx (`keyword`, `ip_adress`, `time`) VALUES  ('$tmp_sphinx', '$remote_ip', '$time')");
target is ignore some keywords,user_agent and referrers.I want ignore some referrer domains.Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

user agent and referer are extracted from the http headers sent to the server within the requst. any vars created from a http header can be spoofed by scripts or browser (I'm surfing now using mobile opera set to send the agent of it's desktop version) I wouldn't spend the time or resources of using a db backed system. just redirect them and call it good.